# sklearn - AttributeError: 'CustomScaler' object has no attribute 'copy'

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook, python-3.8

When i write my custom scaler to scale my data without scaling dummies i've already created, i get an error regarding custom scaler not having copy?

```
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

class CustomScaler(BaseEstimator,TransformerMixin): 
    
    def __init__(self,columns,copy=True,with_mean=True,with_std=True):
    
        self.scaler = StandardScaler(copy,with_mean,with_std)
        self.columns = columns
        self.mean_ = None
        self.var_ = None
    
    def fit(self, X, y=None):
    
        self.scaler.fit(X[self.columns], y)
        self.mean_ = np.mean(X[self.columns])
        self.var_ = np.var(X[self.columns])
        return self

    def transform(self, X, y=None, copy=True):
    
        init_col_order = X.columns
        X_scaled = pd.DataFrame(self.scaler.transform(X[self.columns]), 
columns=self.columns)       
        X_not_scaled = X.loc[:,~X.columns.isin(self.columns)]        
        return pd.concat([X_not_scaled, X_scaled], axis=1)[init_col_order]
```

-> These are my unscaled columns

```
unscaled_inputs.columns.values
array(['Reason_1', 'Reason_2', 'Reason_3', 'Reason_4', 'Month',
   'Day of the week', 'Transportation Expense', 'Distance to Work',
   'Age', 'Daily Work Load Average', 'Body Mass Index', 'Education',
   'Children', 'Pets'], dtype=object)
```

-> dummy variables i don't want to scale

```
columns_to_omit = ['Reason_1', 'Reason_2', 'Reason_3', 'Reason_4','Education']
```

-> variables i want to scale

```
columns_to_scale = [x for x in unscaled_inputs.columns.values if x not in columns_to_omit]
```

-> Giving input data "columns_to_scale" to my "CustomScaler"

```
absenteeism_scaler = CustomScaler(columns_to_scale)
```

-> i get this warning

```
C:\Users\prati\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py:70: 
FutureWarning: Pass copy=True, with_mean=True, with_std=True as keyword args. From 
version 1.0 (renaming of 0.25) passing these as positional arguments will result in an 
error
  warnings.warn(f"Pass {args_msg} as keyword args. From version "
```

-> When i fit my "absenteeism_scaler" to my "unscaled_inputs", i get an error, but the error doesn't stop my code from executing further

```
absenteeism_scaler.fit(unscaled_inputs)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\formatters.py in __call__(self, obj, include, 
exclude)
    968 
    969             if method is not None:
--> 970                 return method(include=include, exclude=exclude)
    971             return None
    972         else:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py in _repr_mimebundle_(self, **kwargs)
    462     def _repr_mimebundle_(self, **kwargs):
    463         """Mime bundle used by jupyter kernels to display estimator"""
--> 464         output = {"text/plain": repr(self)}
    465         if get_config()["display"] == 'diagram':
    466             output["text/html"] = estimator_html_repr(self)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py in __repr__(self, N_CHAR_MAX)
    258             n_max_elements_to_show=N_MAX_ELEMENTS_TO_SHOW)
    259 
--> 260         repr_ = pp.pformat(self)
    261 
    262         # Use bruteforce ellipsis when there are a lot of non-blank characters

~\Anaconda3\lib\pprint.py in pformat(self, object)
    151     def pformat(self, object):
    152         sio = _StringIO()
--> 153         self._format(object, sio, 0, 0, {}, 0)
    154         return sio.getvalue()
    155 

~\Anaconda3\lib\pprint.py in _format(self, object, stream, indent, allowance, context, 
level)
    168             self._readable = False
    169             return
--> 170         rep = self._repr(object, context, level)
    171         max_width = self._width - indent - allowance
    172         if len(rep) > max_width:

~\Anaconda3\lib\pprint.py in _repr(self, object, context, level)
    402 
    403     def _repr(self, object, context, level):
--> 404         repr, readable, recursive = self.format(object, context.copy(),
    405                                                 self._depth, level)
    406         if not readable:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\_pprint.py in format(self, object, context, 
maxlevels, level)
    178 
    179     def format(self, object, context, maxlevels, level):
--> 180         return _safe_repr(object, context, maxlevels, level,
    181                           changed_only=self._changed_only)
    182 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\_pprint.py in _safe_repr(object, context, 
maxlevels, level, changed_only)
    423         recursive = False
    424         if changed_only:
--> 425             params = _changed_params(object)
    426         else:
    427             params = object.get_params(deep=False)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\_pprint.py in _changed_params(estimator)
     89     estimator with non-default values."""
     90 
---> 91     params = estimator.get_params(deep=False)
     92     init_func = getattr(estimator.__init__, 'deprecated_original',
     93                         estimator.__init__)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py in get_params(self, deep)
    193         out = dict()
    194         for key in self._get_param_names():
--> 195             value = getattr(self, key)
    196             if deep and hasattr(value, 'get_params'):
    197                 deep_items = value.get_params().items()

AttributeError: 'CustomScaler' object has no attribute 'copy'

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\formatters.py in __call__(self, obj)
    700                 type_pprinters=self.type_printers,
    701                 deferred_pprinters=self.deferred_printers)
--> 702             printer.pretty(obj)
    703             printer.flush()
    704             return stream.getvalue()

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\lib\pretty.py in pretty(self, obj)
    392                         if cls is not object \
    393                                 and callable(cls.__dict__.get('__repr__')):
--> 394                             return _repr_pprint(obj, self, cycle)
    395 
    396             return _default_pprint(obj, self, cycle)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\lib\pretty.py in _repr_pprint(obj, p, cycle)
    698     """A pprint that just redirects to the normal repr function."""
    699     # Find newlines and replace them with p.break_()
--> 700     output = repr(obj)
    701     lines = output.splitlines()
    702     with p.group():

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py in __repr__(self, N_CHAR_MAX)
    258             n_max_elements_to_show=N_MAX_ELEMENTS_TO_SHOW)
    259 
--> 260         repr_ = pp.pformat(self)
    261 
    262         # Use bruteforce ellipsis when there are a lot of non-blank characters

~\Anaconda3\lib\pprint.py in pformat(self, object)
    151     def pformat(self, object):
    152         sio = _StringIO()
--> 153         self._format(object, sio, 0, 0, {}, 0)
    154         return sio.getvalue()
    155 

~\Anaconda3\lib\pprint.py in _format(self, object, stream, indent, allowance, context, 
level)
    168             self._readable = False
    169             return
--> 170         rep = self._repr(object, context, level)
    171         max_width = self._width - indent - allowance
    172         if len(rep) > max_width:

~\Anaconda3\lib\pprint.py in _repr(self, object, context, level)
    402 
    403     def _repr(self, object, context, level):
--> 404         repr, readable, recursive = self.format(object, context.copy(),
    405                                                 self._depth, level)
    406         if not readable:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\_pprint.py in format(self, object, context, 
maxlevels, level)
    178 
    179     def format(self, object, context, maxlevels, level):
--> 180         return _safe_repr(object, context, maxlevels, level,
    181                           changed_only=self._changed_only)
    182 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\_pprint.py in _safe_repr(object, context, 
maxlevels, level, changed_only)
    423         recursive = False
    424         if changed_only:
--> 425             params = _changed_params(object)
    426         else:
    427             params = object.get_params(deep=False)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\_pprint.py in _changed_params(estimator)
     89     estimator with non-default values."""
     90 
---> 91     params = estimator.get_params(deep=False)
     92     init_func = getattr(estimator.__init__, 'deprecated_original',
     93                         estimator.__init__)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py in get_params(self, deep)
    193         out = dict()
    194         for key in self._get_param_names():
--> 195             value = getattr(self, key)
    196             if deep and hasattr(value, 'get_params'):
    197                 deep_items = value.get_params().items()

AttributeError: 'CustomScaler' object has no attribute 'copy'
```

-> it still gives me output, but i don't understand, that if i get an error the code should stops executing?, but it runs afterwards,
P.S - this is just the left half of the data, as i can't fit all the data here, sry for that....

```
scaled_inputs = absenteeism_scaler.transform(unscaled_inputs)
scaled_inputs

   Reason_1 Reason_2    Reason_3    Reason_4    Month   Day of the week   Transportation 
                                                                                Expense
0     0        0           0           1       0.182726    -0.683704        1.005844
1     0        0           0           0       0.182726    -0.683704       -1.574681    
2     0        0           0           1       0.182726    -0.007725       -0.654143    
3     1        0           0           0       0.182726    0.668253         0.854936      
4     0        0           0           1       0.182726    0.668253         1.005844
```

Update 1: as i removed
copy=True,with_mean=True,with_std=True from **init**, my error got resolved, but i think the scaled data will be an "inplace" change & the mean and S.D thing, and so if i don't want to make inplace changes to my data what can i do???

Update 2: is it because copy, with_mean, and with_std are "True" by default?? just check the StandardScaler library on sklearn

```
def _init__(self,columns): 
    self.scaler = StandardScaler()
    self.columns = columns 
    self.mean = None 
    self.var_ = None
```

Comment: While I appreciate you continuing to debug and adding those details to the question, it's gotten a bit sprawling.  Try to edit it down to a single question (in the future at least).

Answer (score 2):

## Positional/keyword warning/error

The first warning (an error for sklearn versions >1.0) is because you're setting keyword arguments of the `StandardScaler` as positional arguments here:

```py
    def __init__(...):
        self.scaler = StandardScaler(copy,with_mean,with_std)
        ...
```

You should change it to use the keywords,

```py
    def __init__(...):
        self.scaler = StandardScaler(copy=copy, with_mean=with_mean, with_std=with_std)
        ...
```

## No attribute `copy` error

This is only being thrown when trying to display the html representation of the transformer, *after* fitting has already succeeded, which is why you're able to continue and transform successfully.

But the issue is more serious than that if you want to make use of the transformer in pipelines, grid searches, etc.  In order to `clone` properly, you need to follow the [specific guidance of the sklearn API](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/developers/develop.html#instantiation), or else provide your own `get_params` and `set_params`.  The `__init__` method should set an attribute for every parameter, and only those attributes.  So here it should be

```py
    def __init__(self, columns, copy=True, with_mean=True, with_std=True):
        self.columns = columns
        self.copy = copy
        self.with_mean = with_mean
        self.with_std = with_std
```

And then make the contained `StandardScaler` at `fit` time:

```py
    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        self.scaler = StandardScaler(copy=self.copy, with_mean=self.with_mean, with_std=self.with_std)
        self.scaler.fit(X[self.columns], y)
        self.mean_ = np.mean(X[self.columns])
        self.var_ = np.var(X[self.columns])
        return self
```

Comment: Thankyou so much!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: def __init__(self,columns):
        self.scaler = StandardScaler()      like this

Comment: Hey i did what you said, but it still gave the "copy" error, so i just removed those parameters as they are default in StandardScaler(), and all errors dropped

Comment: I just tested and it works for me locally.  I've taken your `transform` but used the last two code blocks of my answer (for `__init__` and `fit` resp.), and applied it to a dataframe `df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [0, 1, 2], 'b': [0, 1, 2]})`, `sc = CustomScaler(['a'])`, `sc.fit(df)`, `sc.transform(df)`.